# Conditional url validation of input with jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to be able to validate an input field has a correctly formatted URL only if the input is not blank. I am checking whether the value of the input is not blank, and if so, validate that it is a URL. However, this seems to oddly be breaking my code and not validating.

```
rules: { 
    domain: {
        required: true
    },
    playerClass: {
        required: true,
    },
    if (adTag.value !== '') {  
        url: true
    }
},
```

Full example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bk7x129p/)

Comment: Please also post the relevant code within the OP.  Do not rely on the jsFiddle.  Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to construct a conditional for something you don't need.  **Without the `required` rule, the other rules are *automatically* ignored when the field is left blank.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking the plugin, because you cannot put a conditional statement within an object literal...

```
rules: {  // <- this is part of an object literal, NOT a function
    domain: {
        required: true
    },
    playerClass: {
        required: true,
    },
    if (adTag.value !== '') {  // <- no good! conditional is outside of a function
        url: true
    }
},
```

A conditional statement can only go inside of a function.

The `rules` option only takes a comma separated list of `key:value` pairs that represent the field `name` where the `value` is its rules.  *Then* you can use a function to construct the parameter for the rule.

You *could* do something like this...

```
rules: {
    domain: {
        required: true
    },
    playerClass: {
        required: true,
    },
    adTag: {
        url: function() {
            // conditional statement to return true or false
        }
    }
},
```

---

> I need to be able to validate an input field ... only if the input is not blank.

Without using the `required` rule, **that is already the default behavior!**

```
rules: {
    domain: {
        required: true
    },
    playerClass: {
        required: true,
    },
    adTag: {
        url: true  // only gets evaluated when the field is not empty
    }
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bk7x129p/1/**

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using an expression inside the definition of a JS object. This is not possible. You can do this instead:

```
    rules: {
        domain: {
            required: true
        },
        playerClass: {
            required: true,
        },
        adTag: {
            url: adTag.value !== ''
        }
    }
```

This has a slightly different effect than what you think your code should have as it always creates the `url` field, but it will be `true` or `false` depending whether `adTag.value !== ''` is `true`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that he uses a jQuery plugin that requires a special formatting. I just corrected the syntax error.

Comment: The question is tagged jQuery Validate and the plugin is used in the jsFiddle, however, the question could have been written better.

Comment: You're making a similar mistake as the OP, where the expression is outside of a function.  Does not work like that: http://jsfiddle.net/bk7x129p/2

Comment: Then I wonder why this has always worked for me. You are free to use any expression that evaluates to a single value behind the colon, and wherever I can use such an expression, the compiler doesn't care whether I put `foo()` or `foo != bar` or `foo + 3`. The point is that you can't use more complex expressions using things like  `if` conditionals unless you wrap it in an anonymous function and that you can't use an expression where the name for the key is expected.

Comment: [Look at my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk7x129p/2).  It's only evaluated once on page load.  It needs to be dynamic, but it's not dynamic unless you use a `function`.